# Are woodlot questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I manage a few wooded acres at the back of my property for firewood. I have some questions related to this acreage that are probably on-topic:

- tree diseases
- diagnosis
- plant identification

My feeling is that these are on-topic because the only difference between these and other questions is the distance from the plant to my house. (And, to some extent, attitude and intensity of management.)

I have other questions about management that I'm not so sure about:

- "What's the best way to thin this area to promote [X]?" [photo attached]

  - (Which is really just a landscaping / plant spacing question on a slightly larger scale -- a couple thousand square feet instead of a couple hundred square feet.)
- "How should I be managing this coppice?"

  - (Which is really just a pruning question, but with slightly different goals and attitude.)
- "How can I make my [slash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_%28logging%29) rot down faster -- or what's a good use for this by-product?"

  - (Which is probably a hugelkultur, mulch, or compost question.)

Comment: Good helpful question; the listed examples are all appropriate subjects

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't see any reason for them to be *off-topic*, but there might be the possibility that it is *too localized*. Let me put it this way: I probably wouldn't close it (as a mod) or vote to close it (as a community member), but the question might run the risk of not attracting answers because not many people would have experience with projects on that scale and because of that, it *could* be construed as being too localized to your specific needs. This only applies to the landscaping questions, as I think questions on diagnosis/diseases/identification won't be all that different from what's currently being asked.

However, it would be terribly unfair to not ask those questions because I feel they'd be a great addition to the knowledge pool. So I suggest that you go ahead and post them and we'll see how it goes. You never know, there might be people lurking around that can answer your question and I personally would be interested in knowing more about large scale landscaping.

I guess we'll have to draw the line somewhere on the scale of the question. So how about an acre or two? Does that sound like a reasonable limit? Anything more than that would be closed immediately as too localized. So definitely no questions like "I work for the USFS and how do I..." :)

Comment: Agreed. Like gardening vs farming, at some point big is too big here. However, from the example questions this doesn't look like it infringes on that. Managing an entire forest/national park though is probably out of scope for any SE site...

Comment: I agree on the scale & scope issue. I can't consider the whole 10ac in my head at one time anyway, and most of what I wonder about is fairly specific. (I guess most good -- answerable -- questions are.)